# Remove lines between two pattern (inclusive of the pattern) using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

My output file is as below:

```
judi#cat file
---ABC---
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
---end_ABC---

---DEF---
line1
line2
line3
line4
---end_DEF---
judi#
```

I need to remove the lines in between the pattern `ABC` and `end_ABC` (inclusive the pattern, then replace with new content; the new content is in a file).

The content of the file varies, so I need to use only the pattern.

```
judi#file1
---ABC---
wordA1
wordA2
wordA3
---end_ABC---
judi#
```

Desired result has to be

```
judi#
---ABC---
wordA1
wordA2
wordA3
---end_ABC---

---DEF---
line1
line2
line3
line4
---end_DEF---
judi#
```

I tried this command:

```
sed '/ABC/,/end_ABC/{/ABC/!{/end_ABC/!d}}' file > file 2
```

But I get this error:

```
sed: command garbled: /ABC/,/end_ABC/{/ABC/!{/end_ABC/!d}}
```

Comment: Your command works for me under GNU sed.  If you are using BSD (OSX) sed, consider adding some semicolons before the closing braces: `}` --> `;}`.

Comment: yes command looks nice (GNU sed), only file+2, that command will delete all lines in range excluding first and last

Comment: in the future, please learn to search S.O. before posting. Your headline 'remove lines between two pattern' (with an 's' on pattern) returns 76 items. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Never use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but even slightly more complicated tasks need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. Just use a flag:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { rep = rep $0 OFS; next }
/---ABC---/ { printf "%s", rep; inBlock=1 }
!inBlock
/---end_ABC---/ { inBlock=0 }
' file1 file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/end_ABC/a ##here' file | sed '/ABC/,/end_ABC/d' | sed '/##here/r file1' | sed '/##here/d' >file2
```

output

```
judi#cat file
judi#file1
---ABC---
wordA1
wordA2
wordA3
---end_ABC---
judi#

---DEF---
line1
line2
line3
line4
---end_DEF---
judi#
```

`a ##here` is appending `##here` after matching `end_ABC`.

`r file1` is inserting text from file1 after finding pattern `##here`.

Comment: I think I am using some other sed not GUN sed as you mentioned .. getting the below error "sed: command garbled: /end_ABC/a ##here" how do I check which sed is am using ?

Comment: sed --version +[link](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/)